# Saving a file locally in Databricks PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am sure there is documentation for this somewhere and/or the solution is obvious, but I've come up dry in all of my searching.

I have a dataframe that I want to export to a text file to my local machine.  The dataframe contains strings with commas, so just display -> download full results ends up with a distorted export.  I'd like to export out with a tab-delimiter, but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to download it locally.

I have

```
match1.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("delimiter", "\t")
.save("file:\\\C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\NewsArticle.txt")
```

but clearly this isn't right.  I suspect it is writing somewhere else (somewhere I don't want it to be...) because running it again gives me the error that the path already exists.  So...  what *is* the correct way?

Comment: Windows uses backslashes for paths, and you'll need to escape them

Comment: Where are you running this? Databricks online? Your local filesystem isn't mounted there... Have you seen https://forums.databricks.com/questions/11730/how-to-download-a-file-from-dbfs-to-my-local-compu.html

Comment: Yup, this worked, after some tweaking. Thanks so much!

Comment: @kodachrome - great! You should post the steps taken to resolve this issue as an answer to this post. This will certainly help others in case they face similar issue in future.

Answer (score 3):

cricket_007 pointed me along the right path--ultimately, I needed to save the file to the Filestore of Databricks (not just dbfs), and then save the resulting output of the xxxxx.databricks.com/file/[insert file path here] link.

My resulting code was:

```
df.repartition(1) \ #repartitioned to save as one collective file
.write.format('csv') \ #in csv format
.option("header", True) \ #with header
.option("quote", "") \ #get rid of quote escaping
.option(delimiter="\t") \ #delimiter of choice
.save('dbfs:/FileStore/df/') #saved to the FileStore
```

Comment: It would have helped if you had clarified in the question that you are working in Databricks...

Comment: You mean, *I* edited the question to put it in the title (and add the `databricks`  tag, too) just before posting my comment above, right? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46017565/revisions

Answer (score 1):

Check if it is present at below location. Multiple part files should be there in that folder.

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

If you want to create a single file (not multiple part files) then you can use `coalesce()`(but note that it'll force one worker to fetch whole data and write these sequentially so it's not advisable if dealing with huge data)

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").\
    option("delimiter", "\t").\
    save("<file path>")
```

Comment: It's not present there, unfortunately.  os.getcwd() returns some directories for Databricks I don't recognize.  It looks like my file is being saved to Databricks' dbfs instead...  I need to figure out a way to download it off there, I guess

Comment: In that case suggestion by @cricket_007 seems to be the possible solution to this problem. Can you try that please?